# Ionic - Enviar post do localhost para API externa PHP

Tags: php, ionic, apache-cordova

Olá!

Estou desenvolvendo um app com Cordova/Ionic e estou tentando enviar dados via post da seguinte maneira:

```
public async login(usuario: string, senha: string): Promise<any[]>{
    let body = new FormData();
    body.append('usuario', usuario);
    body.append('senha', senha);

    let response: any = await this.http
        .post(this.api.url + '?model=usuario&function=login', body, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8',
                'Token': this.api.token
            }
        })
        .toPromise()
        .catch(error => console.log(error));

    console.dir(response);

    if(response == null){
        response = [];
    }

    return response;
}
```

Acontece que estou no localhost e a api num site php externo. Já consegui fazer requisições via get, mas o post não funciona, a api não recebe nenhum dado.

Para contornar problemas de cross origin fiz uma definição de proxys no arquivo ionic.config.json.

Quando eu executo a função que realiza o POST, consigo ver quatro requisições sendo enviadas usando o debug do chrome:

---

Request URL: http://localhost:8100/api?model=usuario&function=login
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 301 Moved Permanently

---

Request URL: http://localhost:8100/api?model=usuario&function=login
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 301 Moved Permanently

---

Request URL: https://www.sitedaapi.com.br/app/api/?model=usuario&function=login
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 200 OK

---

Request URL: https://www.sitedaapi.com.br/app/api/?model=usuario&function=login
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK

...

Parece que onde seria para enviar um POST acaba enviando um GET.

Answer (score 1):

Já resolvi o problema. Eram duas coisas:

1 - No arquivo ionic.config.json eu coloquei o endereço de proxyUrl errado, estava faltando o 'www' (por algum motivo fazer requisições GET funcionava mesmo sem o 'www')

2 - Removi o 'Content-Type' do 'Header' da requisição e assim consegui receber os dados enviados via post no formato de array no PHP.